# R: anova(lm): What is the Sum Sq when we have two inputs

Tags: r, regression, anova, linear-model, sums-of-squares

What is the formula to calculate the Sum sq column for the inputs?

Answers to some other questions state, that it should be

$RSS = \sum (\hat Y_i -\bar Y)^2$,

yet this is false, it only gives the sum of those values for all input.

In this example anova picture, I want to know the formula to calculate 162392 and 3048.

[image]